# Last occurance of a char in a string

Tags: c, string

This function is to find out the last occurance of a char in a string. eg.

```
Enter a string: abcdefdfdfghh
Enter the target char in the string: f
Resultant string = fghh
```

I know there is something terribly wrong with my pointers. Can someone help me correct it?

```
char *strrchr2(char *s, char chr);

int main()
{
     printf("Enter a string value: \n");
     gets_s(s, sizeof(s));
     printf("Enter the character: \n");
     scanf_s("%c", &chr, 1);
     printf("Resultant string is: %s\n",*(strrchr2(s, chr)));
     _getch();
     return 0;
}


char *strrchr2(char *s, char ch1)
{

    char ns_q4[150];
    char *ns_ptr;
    int count = 0;
    char ans;

    int i = 0;
    ns_ptr = ns_q4;
    while (*(s + i) != '\0')
    {

        count++;
        i++;
    }
    s = &s[0];

  /*iterates from back,breaks when match found and from there iterates newly till end*/


    for (int j = count; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        if (*(s + j) = ch1)
        {
            for (int k = j; k < count; k++)
            {

                *ns_ptr = s[k];  
                ns_ptr++;
            }

            break;          }
    }
    ns_ptr = ns_q4;
    ans = *ns_ptr;

    return ans;

}
```

Comment: Define "something is wrong with my pointers" - If something is wrong, you must have some evidence that there's a problem. Please show us the evidence.

Comment: you can just debug it

Comment: The statement `s = &s[0];` does nothing at all. It is equivalent to `s = s;`. Edit: That's not the problem with the code, however. Rather, I just thought I'd point that out.

Comment: I don't see `s` declared?  Am I overlooking it, or did you forget to show us?

Comment: Also, your `strrchr2` function is declared to return a `char *` but it is actually just returning a single `char`.

Comment: The error is pointing at the point `printf("Resultant string is: %s\n",*(strrchr2(s, chr)));`. That was why I felt the problem was with pointers.

Answer (score 3):

Use `==` instead of `=`
replace `if (*(s + j) = ch1)` with `if (*(s + j) == ch1)`

also, null teminate it when you are done:

```
ns_ptr++;
*ns_ptr = '\0';
```

and this is not required:

```
s = &s[0]
```

you are not changing what `s` points to

Answer (score 2):

There's no need for more than one loop here. All you need to do to find the last occurrence of `ch1` in `s` is this:

```
char *last = NULL;
while (*s != '\0') {
  if (*s == ch1)
    last = s;
  ++s;
}
return last;
```

**Update:** Attempting to be more efficient by iterating from the end of the string is pointless, since you first have to *find* the end of the string first. Whether you do it with an extra loop, or if you call `strlen()`, the result is that you are iterating the entire length of the string just to find the end, and then iterating some additional amount backwards to find the last occurrence. My method iterates the entire string, once and only once. The only way it is more efficient to start from the end of the string is if you already know where the end is in advance, and you can pass that information in to `strrchr2()` as an additional parameter so that `strrchr2()` doesn't have to waste time trying to find the end again every time it is called.

Comment: Not true. Walking from the end, as in your solution, requires that you first *find* the end of the string. Thus, you are walking the entire string from start to end in order to find the end, and then additionally walking some distance backwards to find the last occurrence of `ch1`. That is a futile attempt at efficiency.

Comment: Point taken.   `strlen` hid that inefficiency. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not even going to try to read your code.

Instead:

```
char *strrchr2(char *s, char ch1)
{
    char* r;  // Return value set to NULL, in case ch1 is not found.
    for(r=NULL; s != '\0'; ++s)
    {
        r = (ch1 == *s)? s : r; // If the character is found...
    }
    return r;
}
```

---

If you don't like the ternary form:

```
char *strrchr2(char *s, char ch1)
{
    char* r;  // Return value set to NULL, in case ch1 is not found.
    for(r=NULL; s != '\0'; ++s)
    {
        if (ch1 == *s)
        {
            r = s; //If the character is found...
        }
    }
    return r;
}
```

---

In a follow up, poster writes:

> "But the error is showing at the statement in the main func-->> printf("Resultant string is: %s\n",*(strrchr2(s, chr)));. How can I correct it?"

1. Shame on you for referencing an error, without quoting the error
   message.  The message is important!
2. Don't make life hard for yourself!  The `%s` format expects a `char*`.  The function returns a `char*`.  You have everything you need!  Why did you add an extra `*( )` around the function??? Why??

Comment: I think the ternary makes this more obfuscated than necessary.  `if(*s==ch1) r = s;`

Comment: But the error is showing at the statement in the main func-->> `printf("Resultant string is: %s\n",*(strrchr2(s, chr)));`. How can I correct it?

Comment: I know that's my mistake, but why wouldn't I ref the error if it popped up at first? Idk why...when I wrote my code this msg wasn't there, but when I corrected, it appeared. Im sorry anyway and thanks for the solution.